# Can't dispatch Vuex actions in router file (non .vue files) in Vue3 and Vuex 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I really need help with this.
I am not able to dispatch any actions from router index.ts file.

My store index is like this:

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import { actions } from "./actions";
import { getters } from "./getters";
import { mutations } from "./mutations";

// ...other code here for state and types etc...

export const store = createStore<State>({
  state,
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations,
});
```

Main.ts file has it like:

```
import {store} from "./store";
const app = createApp(App).use(router).use(store);
// ...other code ...
```

In router, I have a `beforeEach`
In side before each if I use something like:

```
import { store } from "../store";
// ...other code...
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // ...other code ...
    store.dispatch(ActionTypes.SignIn);
    // ...other code ...
}
```

I am getting this error
**[vuex] unknown action type: SignIn**

Syntax is all correct I guess as it works in .vue files. Please help, let me know what I am doing wrong here. I have seen some examples for Vue 2 which work but Vue 3 and Vuex 4 not working for me. I can share more details in code if needed. Thanks in advance. If it works for me I will upvote and accept your answer :)
If some can try this same scenario locally please let me know with example.

Comment: What does the content of `actions.ts` look like?

Comment: I have a simple action (there is other code surrounding it too.). This action works fine when I dispatch from a Vue file (setup function).
async [ActionTypes.SignIn]({ state }) {
    console.log(“Signin action envoked”);
}.
There are no syntax errors. I just have not seen any example online that use Vue 3 and Vuex 4 for this scenarion :( :(

Comment: @AmanDeepSharma I cannot reproduce the problem with the code shown in question. Please update the question to show the contents of `actions.ts`. Or share a link to a reproduction of the problem.

Comment: No repro ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-haze-us8zx?file=/src/router/index.ts

Comment: Please edit your question to show in both `actions.ts` and your router, exactly where `ActionTypes` comes from. Please also show how you define the `ActionTypes` values